# AngularJS handling rejected resources in $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I'm trying to handle errors with my resources, and then handle rejection of resources in my `$q.all()`.

This is my code:

```
var user = User.get({id: 1}, function() {
    // Success
}, function(response) {
    // Error
    return $q.reject(response);
});

var promiseList = [user];
$q.all(promiseList).then(function(){
  // Success <-- this seems to run all the time
  }, function(response) {
    // Error <-- this never seems to run but I want it to
});
```

When my User resource receives a 404, the error callback handles it and returns a `$q.reject`.

However the **success** callback in my `$q.all` gets called, not my **error** callback. I would've thought because I am rejecting my promise the `$q.all` error callback would be fired?

*I appreciate I only have 1 item in my `promiseList` but that shouldn't make a difference should it?*

Comment: i think you would need [user.$promise] to get the expected result.

Comment: What arguments does the success callback receive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*According to Michael in the comments*

I changed

```
var promiseList = [user];
```

To this:

```
var promiseList = [user.$promise];
```

And now the `$q.reject()` is being picked up by the `$q.all()`.

Awesome, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I wasnt't able to find out why my $q.all() isn't working properly. After hours of searching I finally found the issue with the promise.promise property!