# $q.all promise is never makes to then

Tags: angularjs

One of my promises during `feeds.forEach` cycle ends up with error. Maybe because this in `LoadData` never executes line `$rootScope.links = urls;` which is inside `then`. How to fix it?

```
app.service('LoadData', ['FeedService', 'EntryStateUrlService', '$q',
 function(FeedService, EntryStateUrlService, $q) {
   this.loadData = function(feedSrc) {

     FeedService.parseFeed(feedSrc).then(EntryStateUrlService.getEntryStateUrl).then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $rootScope.links = data;
     });
   }
 }
]);

app.service('FeedService', function($http, $q) {
 this.parseFeed = function(url) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url))
     .success(function(res) {

       deferred.resolve(res.data.responseData.feed.entries);
     }).error(function() {
       deferred.reject();
     });
   return deferred.promise;
 }
});

app.service('EntryStateUrlService', ['$state', '$q',
 function($state, $q) {

   this.getEntryStateUrl = function(feeds) {

     var deferred = $q.defer();
     var idx = 0,
       promises = [],
       promise = null;
     feeds.forEach(function(e) {
       promise = $http.jsonp(e.link).success(function(data) {
         /*stuff*/
        e['entryStateUrl'] = data.link; // UPDATED
         deferred.resolve(data);
       });
       promises.push(promise);

     }); //forEach
     return $q.all(promises);
   }
 }
]);
```

**UPDATE**
I don't really understand how `$q.all` as a big promise object composite of many other promises will deliver `data` to service `LoadData`....

**UPDATE2**

[It seems like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944922/what-happens-with-q-all-when-some-calls-work-and-others-fail) since one promise fails (because the one of the urls is invalid) `$q.all` fails and never makes to `then()`. How to go around that? I need to get all data from all successful promises.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: One call `$http.jsonp` in `EntryStateUrlService` fails. Chrome console prints out red `GET` record. Others succeed. When setting break-point on `$rootScope.links = urls;` it never stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is you'll need to inject `$rootScope` in order to use it:

```
app.service('LoadData', ['FeedService', 'EntryStateUrlService', '$q', '$rootScope',
 function(FeedService, EntryStateUrlService, $q, $rootScope) {
    //...
 }
]);
```

Also in the Q library there's a method called `allSettled` that will allow you to view all the promise results even if one fails. The angular $q does not have this method, but several people have found it useful so they've created extensions for it. Here's an example of one on a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Aaronius/46ae4a0f8ff052cd24f0):

```
angular.module('qAllSettled', []).config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate) {
    var $q = $delegate;
    $q.allSettled = function(promises) {
      return $q.all(promises.map(function(promise) {
        return promise.then(function(value) {
          return { state: 'fulfilled', value: value };
        }, function(reason) {
          return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
        });
      }));
    };
    return $q;
  });
});
```

Using this method will return all results, whether rejected or not. The returned object will have a `state` property that will tell you the status of the promise:

```
return $q.allSettled(promises);
```

Then you can check the status of each promise and add it to the links as needed:

```
FeedService.parseFeed(feedSrc)
    .then(EntryStateUrlService.getEntryStateUrl)
    .then(function(results) {
        $scope.links = [];
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
                $scope.links.push(result.value);
            } else {
                var reason = result.reason;
            }
        });
});
```

[Plunker Demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/HczTm71OAbb7FlYgFQqd?p=preview)

Comment: There is a problem with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342963/strange-behavior-promise-returned-twice