# Function when several http methods have completed in Angular factory

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a factory that submits a POST request with data.

Here is the factory:

```
app.factory('Quotes', ['$http',function($http, $q) {

  var urlBase = 'http://test-url.com';
  var Quotes = {};

  Quotes.createQuote = function (data) {
    return $http.post(urlBase + '/', data)
  };

  return Quotes;
}]);
```

I have an array of objects, and each object needs to be submitted separately in it's own POST request.  I have this controller..

I am passing $scope.array into the saveQuote() function.

```
$scope.saveQuote = function(data){
    $rootScope.loading = true;

    angular.forEach(data, function(quote){

      Quotes.createQuote(quote)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            $rootScope.status = {header: "Success", message: "Success", type: "success"};
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.status = {header: "Error", message: data};
        });         
    });
}
```

How do i create a function when ALL of the post requests have completed?

**UPDATE:**

Also, how do i output each error response for each POST?  It seems the answer below outputs only one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the $q service

```
$scope.saveQuote = function(data){
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    var createdQuotes = [];

    angular.forEach(data, function(quote){
      createdQuotes.push(Quotes.createQuote(quote));         
    });

    $q.all(createdQuotes).then(function() {
       //do something now that all the quotes are created

       $rootScope.loading = false;
       $rootScope.status = {header: "Success", message: "Success", type: "success"};
    }, function(data) {
       $rootScope.status = {header: "Error", message: data};
    });
}
```

`Quote.createQuote` will have to return the promise though to make this work.

And better yet, you can change the `forEach` to `map` to reduce the first part to one line like this:

```
var createdQuotes = data.map(Quotes.createQuote);
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This works.  However, it only seems to be capturing the error response for one of the calls.  How would i collate and display the error response for each call, as the 2 submissions could contain different errors.

Comment: After the first error, `$q.all` doesn't care about the rest of the requests and immediately calls its error handler. To handle each error, you could keep your original `forEach`, and add an error handler for each call when you push it onto `createdQuotes`. If you're wanting to wait on all of the responses to come back, error or not, you might could use the library referenced in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32008390/1636157